# How to click and enter in text editor file using web driver. . I have tried various locators but not working

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver, ajax-element-locator-factory

[image: This is the view where need to click first on div than need to send values through sendKeys]

Here is the `HTML` code look like on inspection

```
<svg _ngcontent-eda-c23="" class="ng-star-inserted" style="top: 535.5px; left: 367px; width: 34px; height: 18px;">
        <!---->
        <!---->
        <circle _ngcontent-eda-c23="" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0)" r="5" editor-control="element-anchor" editor-control-for="f2bc08a7-565f-448f-aa66-7447b1053ec8" editor-control-type="top-left" cx="0" cy="0" style="cursor: nwse-resize;" class="ng-star-inserted">
        </circle>
        <circle _ngcontent-eda-c23="" fill="#88c6ff" r="4" cx="0" cy="0" style="cursor: nwse-resize;" class="ng-star-inserted">
        </circle>
        <!---->
        <!---->
        <!---->
        <circle _ngcontent-eda-c23="" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0)" r="5" editor-control="element-anchor" editor-control-for="f2bc08a7-565f-448f-aa66-7447b1053ec8" editor-control-type="top-middle" cx="17" cy="0" style="cursor: ns-resize;" class="ng-star-inserted">
        </circle>
        <circle _ngcontent-eda-c23="" fill="#88c6ff" r="4" cx="17" cy="0" style="cursor: ns-resize;" class="ng-star-inserted">
        </circle>
        <!---->
        <!---->
        <!---->
        <circle _ngcontent-eda-c23="" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0)" r="5" editor-control="element-anchor" editor-control-for="f2bc08a7-565f-448f-aa66-7447b1053ec8" editor-control-type="top-right" cx="34" cy="0" style="cursor: nesw-resize;" class="ng-star-inserted">
        </circle>
        <circle _ngcontent-eda-c23="" fill="#88c6ff" r="4" cx="34" cy="0" style="cursor: nesw-resize;" class="ng-star-inserted">
        </circle>
        <!---->
        <!---->
        <!---->
        <circle _ngcontent-eda-c23="" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0)" r="5" editor-control="element-anchor" editor-control-for="f2bc08a7-565f-448f-aa66-7447b1053ec8" editor-control-type="middle-right" cx="34" cy="9" style="cursor: ew-resize;" class="ng-star-inserted">
        </circle>
        <circle _ngcontent-eda-c23="" fill="#88c6ff" r="4" cx="34" cy="9" style="cursor: ew-resize;" class="ng-star-inserted">
        </circle>
        <!---->
        <!---->
        <!---->
        <circle _ngcontent-eda-c23="" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0)" r="5" editor-control="element-anchor" editor-control-for="f2bc08a7-565f-448f-aa66-7447b1053ec8" editor-control-type="middle-left" cx="0" cy="9" style="cursor: ew-resize;" class="ng-star-inserted">
        </circle>
        <circle _ngcontent-eda-c23="" fill="#88c6ff" r="4" cx="0" cy="9" style="cursor: ew-resize;" class="ng-star-inserted">
        </circle>
        <!---->
        <!---->
        <!---->
        <circle _ngcontent-eda-c23="" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0)" r="5" editor-control="element-anchor" editor-control-for="f2bc08a7-565f-448f-aa66-7447b1053ec8" editor-control-type="bottom-left" cx="0" cy="18" style="cursor: nesw-resize;" class="ng-star-inserted">
        </circle>
        <circle _ngcontent-eda-c23="" fill="#88c6ff" r="4" cx="0" cy="18" style="cursor: nesw-resize;" class="ng-star-inserted">
        </circle>
        <!---->
        <!---->
        <!---->
        <circle _ngcontent-eda-c23="" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0)" r="5" editor-control="element-anchor" editor-control-for="f2bc08a7-565f-448f-aa66-7447b1053ec8" editor-control-type="bottom-middle" cx="17" cy="18" style="cursor: ns-resize;" class="ng-star-inserted">
        </circle>
        <circle _ngcontent-eda-c23="" fill="#88c6ff" r="4" cx="17" cy="18" style="cursor: ns-resize;" class="ng-star-inserted">
        </circle>
        <!---->
        <!---->
        <!---->
        <circle _ngcontent-eda-c23="" fill="rgba(0,0,0,0)" r="5" editor-control="element-anchor" editor-control-for="f2bc08a7-565f-448f-aa66-7447b1053ec8" editor-control-type="bottom-right" cx="34" cy="18" style="cursor: nwse-resize;" class="ng-star-inserted">
        </circle>
        <circle _ngcontent-eda-c23="" fill="#88c6ff" r="4" cx="34" cy="18" style="cursor: nwse-resize;" class="ng-star-inserted">
        </circle>
        <!---->
        <!---->
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using the approach like:

```
//NODE_NAME_YOU_ARE_LOOKING_UP[OTHER_FILTERS]
```

However when you look up for svg elemnents in html page you need to use the following pattern:

```
//*[name()='NODE_NAME_YOU_ARE_LOOKING_UP' and OTHER_FILTERS]
```